# Adding cookie to HttpServletRequest and retrieving cookie from HttpServletResponse using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am using Mockito to mock `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`. I want to add cookie in the the mock request I am creating. How can I do so?

Also I am setting the cookie in the response at the server side. How can I retrieve the cookie from the mock response sent by the server?

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like this.

```
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestClass {

    private MockHttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        servletRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        Cookie[] cookies = new Cookie[]{
            new Cookie("test_key", "test_value")
        };
        servletRequest.setCookies(cookies);
    }

    @Test
    public void methodTest() {
        Assert.assertEquals("test_value", servletRequest.getCookies() 
        [0].getValue());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

class ComponentTests {

    private HttpServletRequest testRequest = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);

    @Test
    void testMethod() {
        Cookie[] testCookies = new Cookie[]{new Cookie("name", "value")};
        Mockito.when(testRequest.getCookies()).thenReturn(testCookies);

        // Assertions
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the request: construct the array, adding any `Cookies` you want, then add the behaviour to the mock:

```
final Cookies[] cookies = new Cookies[] { ... };

final HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
given(request.getCookies()).thenReturn(cookies);

... pass to controller/servlet etc ...
```

For the response you create the mock and then verify the `addCookie` call by either using an [`ArgumentCaptor`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) to capture the actual cookie passed to `addCookie`:

```
final ArgumentCapor<Cookie> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Cookie.class);

verify(response).addCookie(captor.capture());

final List<Cookie> cookies = captor.getValue();

... perform asserion on cookies ...
```

Or build the expected cookie and verify:

```
final Cookie expectedCookie = ...

verify(response).addCookie(expectedCookie);
```

Personally I prefer not using an `ArgumentCaptor` but it largely depends on your test.

Answer (score 1):

Use MockHttpServletResponse that implements HttpServletResponse. It has getCookies / getCookie method on which assertions can be done.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do things is to use Spring's `MockHttpServletRequest` and `MockHttpServletResponse`.

They are wrapper implementation with getters for cookie. These are exactly what you need to ensure that cookie setup can be verified. Mockito isn't sufficient here.